# function causing script to stop in php

Tags: php, function, syntax-error, runtime-error

PHP 5.5.3 on Apache 2.0
I hate asking what seems to be such a simple question, but I'm completely stuck on what may be causing this problem.

I have a function that I wrote to perform a simple calculation in the middle of a simple decision structure.  If I include the function as part of the main php file I'm working with the file won't run at all.  If I put the function in a separate file and require that file the script won't run past the require.  If I put the function in a class in a separate file, then require that file and create an object form that class it again stops at the require line.  And doesn't throw any errors!

I've tried it with the same calculation and decision structure basically in the main file, as long as I comment out the require and object creation it runs fine all the way through.  As soon as I replace the require and object creation (or past the function into the main file) the problems begin again.

Am I missing something syntactically that's throwing a silent error???  I'm really at a loss especially since the problem is on a function (well now a method) this simple!!!!

First.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Midi Stuff Sandbox & Testing</title>
</head>

    <body>
<?php
    require('./fun.class.php');
    $procs = new TheseFunctions();

    $string1 = "This is a string to try.";
    $array1 = explode(" ", $string1);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array1);
    echo "\t</pre>\n";
    echo $procs->getTempo(4, 7);

    if (strlen($array1[1]) != 0)
    {
        $first = strlen($array1[0]);
        $second = strlen($array1[1]);

        echo "It's: " . ($first / $second);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "WTF" . $array[1];
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The file with the function in it (I thought maybe it needed to be contained in a class which is why it is here, but whether it is or isn't, or is just part of the original php file it still causes the script to stop without an error): file is fun.class.php

```
<?php
class TheseFunctions
{

function getTempo($first, $second){

    if ($second != 0)
    {
            $result1; 
            $current;
            $current = ($first / $second);

    } else {
        $current = $first;
    }

    return $current;
}
}
?>
```

so yeah, I realize I'm probably missing something completely obvious, and I have no idea what it is.

**EDIT**
after working on it for 30+ minutes (nothing changed) it seems to be working fine now.  I really have no idea why it wasn't (in 3 different ways) nor why it wasn't giving me a particular message.  I apologize, but appreciate the answers trying to help.  Maybe MAMP was just trying to give me a migraine >.<

Comment: Can you tell us what the error message you are getting, is?

Comment: Your code works just fine for me (5.5.0) even with the class included. Are you including the file from correct location?

Comment: not receiving any error messages.
And I'm including from correct location (just double checked).
The thing that's really confusing me is that if I include the function (outside of the class, with the proper function call, removing the object name) it causes the same problem (the script just stops running where the function is and doesn't resume, no error thrown).  I'm using MAMP as a test environment, but I've never had problems like this with PHP or MAMP before and confused.

Comment: To test if the require is reading the correct file, you could uncomment the line and replace the function/class with an echo/print. Then if the file is loading correctly you will see the echo in your output. If not then there is an issue when the file is being loaded. You could also use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script to make sure that error messaging is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Some servers require you to include files like below, you might try this.

try : require( dirname(__ FILE __).'/fun.class.php');

I had this problem  on different typres of servers, some accept  include other need the dirname combo.

Be sure to check the location of the fun.class !! I think this is the problem really.

You dont really need the two vars in the class that are undefined:

$result1; 
$current;

Comment: or you could use `include(__DIR__ . "/fun.class.php");`

Answer (score 0):

Seems perfectly ok. The result is:

```
Array
(
[0] => This
[1] => is
[2] => a
[3] => string
[4] => to
[5] => try.
)
0.57142857142857It's: 2
```

I've tried the outer file option, as well as the inside First.php class option and it seems to be ok. Things I would check are: put

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>
```

to the very top of the First.php AND get rid of those lines in class:

```
$result1; 
$current;
```

Also, check the path (./) - does it include the file really ?

```
if(!require('./fun.class.php')){
    echo "There is no such file";
}
```